# malloc : error double free with printf and a NULL wchar_t*

Tags: c, macos, gcc, printf

I'm trying to port an application from Linux to Mac Os X (leopard), but when I execute it, I have this error message : `malloc: *** error for object 0x100160 : double free`.

I've reproduced this issue with the code below :

```
//main.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    wchar_t *b=NULL;
    printf("a=%ls, b=%ls \n", L"a", b);
}
```

Compiled with gcc:

```
gcc main.cpp -o test
```

The output of the execution:

```
a=a, b=(null)
test (5337) malloc: *** error for object 0x100160 : double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

It's strange because if I use this line : `printf("a=%ls, b=%ls", b, b)`, no error are printed.
Furthermore, I can't use `wprintf(L"a=%ls, b=%ls", a, b)`.
On Fedora 13, this program don't print any error.

Is it a printf bug?
How can I remove this error?

Comment: Wait, you're asking why you run into problems when you pass a NULL pointer into a function that generally expects it to point to data?

Comment: I can't get any explanation of this behavior except a bug in CRT library.

Comment: @Al: Are you suggesting that there's some guarantee printf will gracefully handle null pointers? I think the explanation you're searching for is "undefined behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Jefromi: As I stated in my comment below, I think that printf should choose a different way of refusing invalid input than corrupting or destroying memory heap. Just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply a bug in `vprintf_l`, which handles `printf` (and presumably all its friends).

Strictly speaking, the library is within its rights to handle this situation by doing whatever it likes, heap corruption included, but judging by the code the intent -- as should be the case for any non-rubbish `printf` implementation -- is to handle `NULL` strings sensibly. There is simply a bug in the code that does this. These things happen.

If an attempt is made to print a `NULL` wide char pointer after a previous non-`NULL` wide char pointer was printed, `vprintf_l` will cock up on the next string argument, or when `vprintf_l` exits. (There may be other ways to get this to happen, too, I suppose - I didn't check.)

The offending code is here:

```
    case 's':
        if (flags & LONGINT) {
            wchar_t *wcp;

            if (convbuf != NULL)
                free(convbuf);
            if ((wcp = GETARG(wchar_t *)) == NULL)
                cp = "(null)";
            else {
                convbuf = __wcsconv(wcp, prec, loc);
                if (convbuf == NULL) {
                    fp->_flags |= __SERR;
                    goto error;
                }
                cp = convbuf;
            }
        } else if ((cp = GETARG(char *)) == NULL)
```

If `GETARG(wchar_t *)` returns `NULL`, `convbuf` will point to the old (and now freed) buffer. Then, when the function exits, there is a double free:

```
if (convbuf != NULL)
    free(convbuf);
```

The same would apply were there another string argument, though in this case the double free happens in the `case 's'` code above:

```
printf("a=%ls, b=%ls c=%ls\n", L"a", b, L"c");
```

The solution of course would be to set `convbuf` to `NULL` after it is freed.

The `printf` code is here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/stdio/vfprintf-fbsd.c

Judging by the disassembly, it is the code that is used for the default runtime in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Great answer.  Another solution would be to move the convbuf check to inside the else -- no need to free it unless you're going to re-use it.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot print NULL pointers as strings, that's undefined behavior.  From the C99 standard, §7.19.6.1/8

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>   ...
>   **s**     If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type. ...
>
> If an `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of `wchar_t` type.

Since NULL pointers are not explicitly allowed, they are disallowed.  You should change your code to something like:

```
printf("a=%ls, b=%ls \n", L"a", b ? b : L"(null)");
```

Comment: printf is allowed to refuse NULL. But please show me where is it written that printf is allowed to corrupt memory heap.

Comment: @Al Kepp undefined behavior is allowed to do anything. Including "appears to work", crash, corrupt memory, set your printer on fire. Other function, e.g. strlen,strcpy, usually just causes a segfault if you use them in an undefined manner. printf happens to corrupt memory

Comment: When the code causes undefined behavior, all bets are off - nobody is going to list all the effects invalid code may cause on all the different platforms. Corrupting stack or heap is really only probable.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu it prints `a=a, b=(null)`, but in general it is not a good idea to try to print NULL strings.

Answer (score -1):

Although it is not a good practice to pass a NULL pointer to printf, from generic point of view I cannot accept a situation when any function (including printf) reacts to an invalid input by destroying memory heap. So although you should not pass a NULL there I consider this behavior as a bug in library. If a function gets invalid arguments it can scream a lot but is not supposed to destroy memory heap.

Of course sometimes it is not possible to know if a parameter is valid, but here we have a NULL constant and it is simple to know that it cannot be dereferenced or something.

Comment: It's certainly not very polite to first print `b=(null)` and then eat flaming death...

Comment: While it's true that it would be better if `printf` reacted better to invalid input, it's not a bug because the C standard does not require it to do so.

Comment: @Adam: So does C standard somewhere declare that it is 100% legal to corrupt memory stack when you get NULL argument where it shouldn't be? I think that C standard refuses to call free twice, so printf violates it here. Maybe I take it wrong and this strange behavior is legal, but I call it "avoidable accident".

Comment: @Al: It's totally legal. Whether it's *good* is a different question; as Adam says, it probably would be nice if printf behaved more kindly. But as far as the standard's concern, this is all good. (And in fact, I'm pretty sure the standard says that the result of a double free is undefined too, which is not "refusing to call it twice".) See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). (That's really C++, but I couldn't find just C, and it's similar.)